# How do I block/clear data for each cell in a column that matches the conditional if statement in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am new to VBA programming in excel and would like to know how to do the following (I have searched google and will post what I have tried here with sample code).

Column G, starting at G11 continuing to the end of the sheet, contains 2 values: either "Full Time" or "Part Time".

In column S, starting at S11 continuing until the end of the sheet, our accountant will enter a Dollar value. The Accountant wants the excel cell in Column G to block/clear out any data and have a popup message saying that "You cannot edit this Cell in Column G as the employee is Part Time".

I used this code, but it only works for Row 11. I would like this to work for every row in Column G. Do you have any pointers or tips? Thanks in advance.
I use the 2 events Change and SelectionChange

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If [$G11] = "Part Time" Then
[$S11].Interior.ColorIndex = 34
[$S11].ClearContents
[$S11].Locked = True
Else
[$S11].Interior.ColorIndex = 12
[$S11].Locked = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If [$G11] = "Part Time" Then
[$S11].ClearContents
[$S11].Locked = True
Else
[$S11].Locked = False

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. I made some assumptions based on what you wrote, so if it doesn't quite fit your data, let me know.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

If Not Intersect(Target, .Columns("S:S")) Is Nothing Then 'only do this if column S is changed

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If range("G" & Target.Row) = "Part Time" Then

        With range("S" & Target.Row)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 34
            .ClearContents
            .Locked = True
        End With

    Else

        With range("S" & Target.Row)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 12
            .Locked = False
        End With

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As range)

If Not Intersect(Target, .Columns("S:S")) Is Nothing Then 'only do this if column S is changed

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If range("G" & Target.Row) = "Part Time" Then

        With range("S" & Target.Row)
            .ClearContents
            .Locked = True
        End With

    Else
        range("S" & Target.Row).Locked = False

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```